# Custom www-data user in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, security, mpm-prefork

I use [apache2-mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) to run one of my web applications with a custom uid and gid, both for audit and security reasons. This works nicely, however I am not sure what kind of privileges this user would need. I am currently doing something like `useradd mywebapp -U -d/tmp -c"Custom webapp User"` but that creates pretty much a regular user.

So first a newbie question: how do I add a 'system' user that can that cannot be used for e.g. ssh'in or does not appear in the login screen on Ubuntu Desktop?

And what kind of privileges would I need to give this user? E.g. I assume that www-data can write to the Apache log files, so it needs something more than a regular user. But at the same time I don't want to give it more privileges than necessary to run my webapp, definitely not root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo useradd username
```

will work just fine for your requirement. It creates the user with unset/random password. If you insist on disabling shell access to the user you could change the shell option for this user to /bin/false with commands like

```
sudo chsh username
```

As for not showing username in GDM login screen, you need to give the username UID below 1000. This makes Ubuntu treat the user as a system user, which then won't show up on the login screen.

Add the user in whatever way you prefer(maybe just like above), and then run:

```
sudo usermod -u 599 username
```

Where 599 is an unused UID below 1000, and username is your new user.

Comment: Is there a smart way I can detect if a UID has been taken? All of this has to end up in an Ubuntu package.

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $3}' | sort -n

Comment: What would be a smart way to find an unused uid between say 500 and 1000?

Comment: there is no inbuilt commmand that i know of that will do the job. How about writing your own script for that !

Comment: Alright. But this does not address the permissions issue. The new user won't have permission to write to access.log / error.log , etc...

Comment: if you want to be able to make everybody able to view central access.log and error.log of apache, chmod o+r access.log and error.log